# Code not working how I expected (Python 3.x.x)

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-3.4

I've recently being self teaching python and I'm making my first attempt at a game. The idea is the user must guess what the answer is (integer) My code is not yet complete but the first half won't work.

My code:

```
highest = 10
answer = 7
guess = int(input("What is your guess?"))
def guessingGame():
    print("try again please")
    guess = int(input("what is your guess?"))

while (int(guess) != answer):

    if (int(guess) < answer):
        print ("Answer is higher!")
        guessingGame();

    elif (int(guess) > answer):
        print ("Answer is lower!")
        guessingGame();
```

No matter whether I enter a value less then the answer(which is 7) or higher, It will always say ;"The answer is higher!" What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: I'm also aware my code might be incredibly buggy/poorly written and would love any criticism/improvements.

Comment: Add the line `global guess` at the top of `guessingGame` function.

Comment: @0O0O0O0 Indentation looks fine to me. It's a program for guessing a number, so they're surely trying to update the variable `guess` by calling `guessingGame` each time user enters a wrong input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `guess` variable that you edit in `guessingGame` is not the same one you are comparing in the while loop.

Adding `global guess` to the top of the `guessingGame`function should solve it.

For future reference, if something is not behaving, it's often useful to print the variables at various stages to see what things are. (for larger programs a debugger is more useful but on stuff like this, printing is fine).

Edit: with respect to the criticism/improvements comment:

- functions should be named after what they do. `guessingGame` should be named something like `updateUserGuess`. Rather than rely on globals I think I'd make that function return the guess and assign the value to the guess variable outside the function.
- the `elif` condition is not needed. If the guess isn't `< answer` and not equal it must be higher
- you call `guessingGame` whether the guess is higher or lower so it can be moved out of the if/else statements
- you are casting the `guess` to an `int` every time you use it (in the `guessingGame` function and then again in each of the conditions). Nothing really wrong with that but it's not necessary. If it's stored as an `int`, use it as one.